# Could Azure service fabric use reverse proxy as edge proxy after load balancer

Tags: asp.net-core, reverse-proxy, azure-service-fabric, kestrel-http-server, weblistener

It is advised that asp net core must use a strong web server such as web listener 
 or a proxy as an internet gateway.  My question is:  is the build in reverse proxy strong enough to be that role?  If I use asp net core + kestrel in my internal service and all external communication goes through reverse proxy after load balancer, is it secure?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no
It's just a proxy with some smart retry logic.

You want to put a WAF, or Azure API manager, in front of it if you want to publish all your internal services to the internet and use kestrel, or use web listener for all your services.

Comment: What's the point of it then if not to be used as a public facing gateway? Where is it stated that it is not recommended for facing public www?

Comment: That is why I asked this question.  Does this reverse proxy use http.sys?  Weblistener can not be used in stateful service.  Kestrel can not be public facing.  It seems reverse proxy should be public facing while routing traffic to a stateful service.  Azure service fabric should provide confirmation if reverse proxy can do job or we need another stronger proxy between reverse proxy and load balancer.

Comment: In the docs page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy, under the section "Reaching microservices via the reverse proxy from outside the cluster", MS is describing that you could setup your LB to use the port of your Proxy. This implies that MS still want you to use a LB infront if it.

Comment: About Kestrel, MS is working on making it stronger so it can be used externaly without IIS or LBs in front if it. The .net Team confirmed this a few month back. I wouldn't be suprised if they anounced this when .Net Core 2 is RTW. It makes sens if the SF team is waiting for this. When Kestrel is supported they can says that you can use the reverse Proxy externaly without LB.

Comment: For Azure fabric service, a load balancer is already provided if you order a cluster.  Is this load balancer - reverse proxy - kestrel config good enough even now?

Comment: You still need the load balancer in front of your reverse proxy or services because the reverse proxy is nothing more than a service like your application services and it will be running on all nodes in your cluster, the load balancer will balance the load to avoid only one proxy handling all the requests and make your services more resilient. Kestrel is not secure enough to be exposed, this is why you should have access to it only inside your cluster. 
As @PerB described, you still need a level of protection, and this will reside in front of your load balancer.

Comment: @DiegoMendes Azure LB is a L4 LB, so offers no protection. So is it not safe to just use PublicIP -> Azure LB -> Resolve to SF RP?

Comment: @Mardoxx, as I said at last part of my message, 'you still need a level of protection, and this will reside in front of your load balancer'. Client -> Domain -> WAF ->LoadBalancer->Proxy->SF Services with kestrel

Comment: @DiegoMendes reverse proxy is built upon a similar API to http.sys so perhaps not necessary?

Comment: The reverse proxy included in service fabric is an application running inside your servers and does not protect your applications from DDos Attacks, Rate Limiting(abuse), IP Filtering, and many other attacks scenarios that a WAF is capable of support, keeping the attacker out of your servers is the better option, in a bigger level will cost you less that handling this inside your applications and servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

"The reverse proxy is built on the same Windows HTTP Server API (http.sys) that WebListener uses which provides the DoS protection that is currently missing from Kestrel." - Vaclav Turecek ([github](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/281#issuecomment-302544466))